# CMake check if the main project was called

Tags: cmake

I've got this kind of project directory design:

```
Main:
    CMakeLists.txt
    subproject1:
         CMakeLists.txt   
    subproject2
         CMakeLists.txt
```

How can I check in subproject1/CMakeLists.txt file if subproject1 cmake was called by the Main project, or as a standalone one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
if( CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR )
# We are building as stand-alone project
project(subproject1)
...
else()
# We are building as part of Main project
endif()
```

Comment: From CMake version 3.21 we can now use the boolean variable `PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL`. See [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL.html)