# CMake project shared dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have:

- a shared library X, which is independent
- a shared library Y, using X
- an executable Z, which uses both X and Y

All of them have their own CMakeLists.txt, and can be configured and built independently.

However, I cannot make the CMakeLists.txt for the executable (Z) to work.

My approach has been this:

```
foreach(clib ${OWN_LIBS})
   set(LIBS "${LIBS} ${clib}")
   set(CLIB_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib${clib}")
   set(CLIB_BUILD_DIR "${CLIB_DIR}/build")

   add_subdirectory("${CLIB_DIR}" "${CLIB_BUILD_DIR}")
   include_directories("${CLIB_DIR}/incl")
   link_directories("${CLIB_BUILD_DIR}")
endforeach(clib)
```

With OWN_LIBS being just "X" in project Y, and being "X Y" in project Z.

This works for project Y, but in project Z, I get:

> CMake Error at ... (add_subdirectory):   The binary directory
>
> ```
> .../libX/build
> ```
>
> is already used to build a source directory.  It cannot be used to
>   build   source directory
>
> ```
> .../libX
> ```
>
> Specify a unique binary directory name.

I also tried trying to create a local build directory, so for e.g. there would be libY/build/deps-libX/ containing the configured and built library X (when used from Y), and Z having this for both X and Y.
Unfortunately, next I ran into:

> add_library cannot create target "X" because another target with
>   the   same name already exists.  The existing target is a shared
>   library created   in source directory
>   "libX".   See
>   documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.

Using ExternalProject is not an option.

Comment: I eventually ended up using the solution detailed at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11217008/128240.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMake - dependencies (headers) between apps/libraries in same project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216408/cmake-dependencies-headers-between-apps-libraries-in-same-project)

Answer (score 8):

An additional answer for others:

I got this error because of a merge "error". In a larger project, after merging, a CMakeLists.txt called "add_subdirectory" twice on the same subdirectory. It causes the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

`X`'s CMakeLists.txt is processed 2 times (`add_subdirectory(X)` is called from both `Z` and `Y`). That makes the target `X` defined multiple times, which violates the policy `CMP0002` (`X` is not globally unique)

For this link situation

```
Z-->Y--->X
 --------^
```

you do not need to call `add_subdirectory(X)` from `Z`'s CmakeLists.txt

```
Z/CmakeLists.txt
   add_subdirectory(Y ...)

Y/CmakeLists.txt
   add_subdirectory(X ...)
```

Comment: Right, but ideally I would not want to Z have to know that Y depends on X. Z's only concern should be that he uses both X and Y. Is there any robust way of doing this?

Comment: `X` and `Y` could be in a [package](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but I'm going to dig into this graveyard as I recently ran into this, again.  My problem space was much like OPs: I have two executables which I'd like to compile separately **or** as part of a larger compile which both link to the same library, which is also compiled through `cmake`.  As this is simply not possible without altering the `CMakeList.txt` of each of the executables, the following answer proved extremely helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13290084

If the project is compiled using the "master" `CmakeList.txt` the linked library is not added in each of the executables.  If an individual executable is compiled, the library is built and linked.  Note that this produces the following within each `CMakeLists.txt`:

Master:

```
add_subdirectory( common )
add_subdirectory( exec1  )
add_subdirectory( exec2  )
```

exec1 and exec2:

```
set( COMMON_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../common )

if ( CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR )
    add_subdirectory( ${COMMON_DIR} ${COMMON_DIR})
endif()
```